# Multiple images display (slideshow) on wpInstalling Page

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup

I have a script for Inno to add an image inside the wpInstalling page, and now I'm trying to put several images to make a slideshow but I couldn't write the required text

This is the text that I have, and I want to make a slideshow. Is this possible? I know I have to add InnoCallback.dll, but I want to get the method.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Codejock Software\ISSkin\VCL\Par1.bmp"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Codejock Software\ISSkin\VCL\Par2.bmp"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Codejock Software\ISSkin\VCL\Par3.bmp"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy


[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
ExtractTemporaryFile('Par1.bmp');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Par2.bmp');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Par3.bmp');
Result := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
BmpFile1, BmpFile2, BmpFile3: TBitmapImage;
begin
if CurPageID = wpInstalling then begin 
  BmpFile1:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BmpFile1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Par1.bmp'));
  BmpFile1.Width:= ScaleX(678);
  BmpFile1.Height:= ScaleY(250);
  BmpFile1.Stretch := True;
  BmpFile1.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
  BmpFile1.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(25);
  BmpFile1.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;

  BmpFile2:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BmpFile2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Par2.bmp'));
  BmpFile2.Width:= ScaleX(678);
  BmpFile2.Height:= ScaleY(250);
  BmpFile2.Stretch := True;
  BmpFile2.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
  BmpFile2.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(25);
  BmpFile2.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;

  BmpFile3:= TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  BmpFile3.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Par3.bmp'));
  BmpFile3.Width:= ScaleX(678);
  BmpFile3.Height:= ScaleY(250);
  BmpFile3.Stretch := True;
  BmpFile3.Left := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left + ScaleX(0); 
  BmpFile3.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + ScaleY(25);
  BmpFile3.Parent:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried the text of the text that I sent before adding my question, but I could not understand how to write the text

Comment: Asking the same question, without telling us what is it, that you do not understand, won't get you anywhere. + Btw, it's called *"code"*, or *"script"*, not *"text"*.

Comment: I know that, but my English is a little weak and I apologize for that. My question is, I want to display a slide show for several pictures on the installer page.